# QT symbol lookup error

Tags: qt

When I run qtcreator from the command line, I get the following error:

```
qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN16QLoggingCategoryD1Ev
```

If I type

```
nm -u /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5
```

I get `no symbols`

The system is ubuntu 16.10

---

**Edit:** as requested by G.M., the results of `ldd qtcreator` are listed as below

> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc73fc9000)
>
> libExtensionSystem.so.1 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.1 (0x00007f8298dc8000)
>
> libAggregation.so.1 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/qtcreator/libAggregation.so.1 (0x00007f8298bc2000)
>
> libUtils.so.1 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/qtcreator/libUtils.so.1 (0x00007f8298818000)
>
> libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f8297fc9000)
>
> libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f8297820000)
>
> libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007f829761a000)
>
> libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f82972bc000)
>
> libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8296ba0000)
>
> libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f82968fb000)
>
> libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f82966de000)
>
> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f829635b000)
>
> libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8296052000)
>
> libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8295e3c000)
>
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8295a72000)
>
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f829586e000)
>       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055c6ee10e000)
>
> libQt5Qml.so.5 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/qtcreator/../Qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f8295274000)
>
> libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f829505a000)
>
> librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8294e51000)
>
> libicui18n.so.56 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f82949b7000)
>
> libicuuc.so.56 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f82945fe000)
>
> libicudata.so.56 => /home/milo/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/./../lib/Qt/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f8292c1b000)
>
> libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8292a19000)
>
> libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8292707000)
>
> libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f82924de000)
>
> libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f82922db000)
>
> libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f82920d7000)
>
> libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f8291ed0000)
>
> libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f8291ccd000)
>
> libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f8291a9d000)
>
> libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f829188b000)
>
> libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f8291688000)
>
> libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f8291481000)
>
> libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f829127f000)
>
> libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8290f45000)
>
> libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f8290d2b000)
>
> libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f8290b26000)
>
> libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8290904000)
>
> libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f82906fd000)
>
> libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f82904ee000)
>
> libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f829027d000)
>
> libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8290079000)
>
> libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f828fe72000)

Comment: The symbol in question is the destructor for `QLoggingCategory` which should be defined in `libQt5Core.so` (I think).  Can you edit your question to show the output from "ldd \`which qtcreator\`".